# libuv: Correct thread management

Tags: c++, multithreading, libuv

I have an application which needs to regularly marshal data between two libuv loops. I need to be able to marshal onto either of the loops at any time from any thread.

My current attempt is below. It crashes, so I have a few questions:

- One crash goes away if I omit the `uv_close` call (which is supposed to free a uv_async handle once it's been processed). How do I correctly free these?
- The other crash is on exit and it's because the loops are still processing work. How can I safely wait for both loops to finish processing signals before I shut them down?
- Is there anything else which I'm blatantly doing wrong here?

```
#include <uv.h>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

std::thread loop1;
std::thread loop2;

std::mutex thread1Mutex;
std::mutex thread2Mutex;

bool thread1Started = false;
bool thread2Started = false;

std::condition_variable thread1StartCondition;
std::condition_variable thread2StartCondition;

uv_loop_t* eventLoop1 = nullptr;
uv_loop_t* eventLoop2 = nullptr;

uv_async_t loop1Shutdown;
uv_async_t loop2Shutdown;

struct AsyncData
{
    std::function<void()> runFunc;
    uv_async_t async;
    std::mutex* mutex;
};

void thread1()
{
    eventLoop1 = static_cast<uv_loop_t*>(malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t)));
    uv_loop_init(eventLoop1);
    uv_async_init(eventLoop1, &loop1Shutdown, [](uv_async_s* req)
    {
        uv_stop(req->loop);
    });
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread1Mutex);
        thread1Started = true;
    }
    thread1StartCondition.notify_one();
    uv_run(eventLoop1, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    uv_close(reinterpret_cast<uv_handle_t*>(&loop1Shutdown), NULL);
    uv_loop_close(eventLoop1);
    free(eventLoop1);
}

void thread2()
{
    eventLoop2 = static_cast<uv_loop_t*>(malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t)));
    uv_loop_init(eventLoop2);
    uv_async_init(eventLoop2, &loop2Shutdown, [](uv_async_s* req)
    {
        uv_stop(req->loop);
    });
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread2Mutex);
        thread2Started = true;
    }
    thread2StartCondition.notify_one();
    uv_run(eventLoop2, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    uv_close(reinterpret_cast<uv_handle_t*>(&loop2Shutdown), NULL);
    uv_loop_close(eventLoop2);
    free(eventLoop2);
}

void runInContext(uv_async_s *re)
{
    auto* asyncData = static_cast<AsyncData*>(re->data);
    asyncData->runFunc();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*asyncData->mutex);
        uv_close(reinterpret_cast<uv_handle_t*>(&asyncData->async), NULL);
    }
    delete asyncData;
}

void runInThread1(const std::function<void()>& work)
{
    auto* d = new AsyncData();
    d->async.data = d;
    d->runFunc = work;
    d->mutex = &thread1Mutex;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread1Mutex);
        uv_async_init(eventLoop1, &d->async, runInContext);
    }
    uv_async_send(&d->async);
}

void runInThread2(const std::function<void()>& work)
{
    auto* d = new AsyncData();
    d->async.data = d;
    d->runFunc = work;
    d->mutex = &thread2Mutex;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread2Mutex);
        uv_async_init(eventLoop2, &d->async, runInContext);
    }
    uv_async_send(&d->async);
}

void runJob()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        std::cout << "Run " << x << " of 100" << std::endl;
        runInThread1([x]()
        {
            std::cout << "Run " << x << " in thread 1" << std::endl;
            runInThread2([x]()
            {
                std::cout << "Run " << x << " in thread 2" << std::endl;
                runInThread1([x]()
                {
                    std::cout << "Run " << x << " back in thread 1 again" << std::endl;
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread1Mutex);
        loop1 = std::thread(&thread1);
        thread1StartCondition.wait(lk, [&]() { return thread1Started; });
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(thread2Mutex);
        loop2 = std::thread(&thread2);
        thread2StartCondition.wait(lk, [&]() { return thread2Started; });
    }


    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        runJob();
    }

    uv_async_send(&loop1Shutdown);
    uv_async_send(&loop2Shutdown);
    loop1.join();
    loop2.join();
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a state machine rather than threads?

Comment: That's not a very helpful comment. I obviously have my reasons for doing this.